# Python used with RobotFramework returning wrong for if else comparison of number with 9 and big numbers

Tags: python, automated-tests, robotframework

This is my python 2.7 code

```
def BigNumber(x, y):
    return x if x > y else y
```

This is my Robot Framework Testcase

```
Big_Number_tc
    [Tags]    Test_TC
    ${number_big}=    BigNumber    91    10000
    log    ${number_big}
```

When I run the code the output shown is always 91, instead of 10000

It is shown correct if I run the python code independently

But when I use Robot framework to run it, it is shown wrong.

It only happens for the numbers which has 9 in it

I have tried with the usual python if else syntax also, but the result is always wrong for the numbers with 9

Is there any reason as well as any fix for this ?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I can only guess that the "numbers" are somehow compared as strings, and then `"91"` really is greater than `"10000"`.  You could check if it really is the `9` which produces the problem or if you also have the issue with `"21"` and `"123"`.

Comment: You probably passed these as string, *not* numbers.

Comment: Yep, you guys are right. When I used `${91} and ${10000}` instead of 91 and 10000, it got fixed. Sorry for the bad example on the question

Comment: Thanks for the tips

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default Robot Framework treat all scalar variables as strings, so your custom keyword is comparing string `"91"` with string `"10000"`. There are two options:

1. Inside your keyword convert arguments to desired data types
2. Explicitly pass numbers to your keyword. To do so use `${}` syntax i.e `${91}`

Comment: Thanks for providing the solution @JaPyR